# Type hints of lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, lazy-loading

In `angular` I want to lazy loaded some modules like `amcharts`.
I know how to do that but what about type hints in editor?

Here is my code:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, NgZone, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
// import * as am4core from '@amcharts/amcharts4/core';
// import * as am4charts from '@amcharts/amcharts4/charts';
// import am4themes_animated from '@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wykres',
  templateUrl: './wykres.component.html',
})
export class WykresComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  private am4core: any;
  private am4charts: any;
  private am4themesAnimated: any;
  chart: any;


  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.loadAmcharts()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('loaded', this.am4charts, this.am4themesAnimated, this.am4core);

          this.am4core.useTheme(this.am4themesAnimated);

          let chart = this.am4core.create('chartdiv', this.am4charts.XYChart);

          chart.paddingRight = 20;

          let data = [];
          let visits = 10;
          for (let i = 1; i < 366; i++) {
            visits += Math.round(
              (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 10
            );
            data.push({
              date: new Date(2018, 0, i),
              name: 'name' + i,
              value: visits
            });
          }

          chart.data = data;

          let dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new this.am4charts.DateAxis());
          dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

          let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new this.am4charts.ValueAxis());
          valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
          valueAxis.renderer.minWidth = 35;

          let series = chart.series.push(new this.am4charts.LineSeries());
          series.dataFields.dateX = 'date';
          series.dataFields.valueY = 'value';

          series.tooltipText = '{valueY.value}';
          chart.cursor = new this.am4charts.XYCursor();

          let scrollbarX = new this.am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
          scrollbarX.series.push(series);
          chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;

          this.chart = chart;
        });
    });
  }

  private async loadAmcharts(): Promise<any> {
    this.am4core = await import('@amcharts/amcharts4/core');
    this.am4charts = await import('@amcharts/amcharts4/charts');
    this.am4themesAnimated = await import('@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated').then(resp => {
      return resp.default;
    });
  }
}
```

In `loadAmcharts` I'm loading modules and assign them to properties. But those are type of any.

If I comment in :

```
import * as am4core from '@amcharts/amcharts4/core';
import * as am4charts from '@amcharts/amcharts4/charts';
import am4themes_animated from '@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated';
```

`amchart` is in main bundle.
Can I lazy load module and have type hints in editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question.

This is more of a TypeScript/IDE issue, e.g. I was able to find this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18656#issuecomment-331526248) which describes the difference between hinting static/dynamic imports:

static:

> [...] .d.ts files are a static representation of what exists at runtime, and can be produced from TypeScript code or written manually for libraries that were not written in TS.

dynamic:

> Not everything can just be inferred - capturing precise behavior would require literally running your program.

So how do we force TS to know what our types are while we code? [TypeScript 2.9 introduced a feature "`import` types"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#import-types), which is just for your IDE, here's how it could work in your case:

```ts
  private am4core: typeof import ('@amcharts/amcharts4/core');
  private am4charts: typeof import ('@amcharts/amcharts4/charts');
  private am4themesAnimated: typeof import ('@amcharts/amcharts4/themes/animated').default;
```

Now you should get code hinting:

```ts
    const core = this.am4core;
    const charts = this.am4charts;
    const animatedTheme = this.am4themesAnimated;

    console.log('loaded', core, charts, animatedTheme);

    core.useTheme(animatedTheme);

    const chart = core.create('chartdiv', charts.XYChart);
```

screenshot (I use VS Code):

[image: screenshot of charts.XYChart having code hinting]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for anwser - I think it is not supported in webStorm which I'm using :/

Comment: That is a possibility. I haven't used web storm (tried it out briefly). I switched over from Atom to VS Code late last year. I was able to get just about all of the features I had carefully chosen and even customized myself and then some. If you're not tied to webStorm, give VS Code a shot.

Comment: You probably already set this up, but here's a page on [TypeScript support in WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/typescript-support.html). Wonder if it will be of any help. Remember, this feature is in TS 2.9+.